# Core Data SUBQUERY: no such column

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

have a problem with a predicate used in an `NSFetcheRequest`.

I want to get all person that have a contact having at least a `phone.internationalNumber == phoneNumberToCompareWith`.

This is the predicate I'm using:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(contact.phones, $phone, $phone.internationalNumber == %@).@count != 0",phoneNumberToCompareWith];
```

Error I receive:

> 2015-03-11 14:54:17.041 appName[1370:390550] Core Data: error:
>   -executeRequest: encountered exception = I/O error for database at 
>       /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F262488E-30BA-414E-979A-D316F53041C3/Documents/appName.sqlite.
>   SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t2.ZINTERNATIONALNUMBER' with
>   userInfo = {
>               NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F262488E-30BA-414E-979A-D316F53041C3/Documents/appName.sqlite";
>               NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 1;
>           }

Entities relation:
[image]

[Edit] : this predicate did the tric:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ in contact.phones.internationalNumber)", phoneNumberToCompareWith];
```

but as i never use SUBQUERY could tell me how do the same thing with SUBQUERY, thanks

Comment: Entity names should have capital letters. e.g. `Phone`, `Contact`, etc.

Comment: as you can see i edit the image manually. in my model they are capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY contact.phones.internationalNumber = %@", phoneNumberToCompareWith];
```

Subquery equivalent is:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(contact.phones, $x, $x.internationalNumber = %@).@count!=0", phoneNumberToCompareWith];
```

So your subquery is correct. I suggest you to open manually sqlite file and exam the data struct.

It is probably the path:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F262488E-30BA-414E-979A-D316F53041C3/Documents/appName.sqlite
```

After that open sql debug to your target to see what exactly Core Data sends to sqlite.

Product -> Scheme -> Edit 
add "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1"

Try to run problematic sql in sqlite3 directly on your db.
Finally, just try to recreate db, but be careful with your data.